# Implementing a live email checker with a syntax email checker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I followed an example, http://formvalidation.io/examples/using-data-returned-validator/, and was able to implement simple validation for email and usernames. I found another demo/example which uses ajax to call a live email checker php script.

What I have not figured out is how to implement (combine) the live username checker with the standard validator so that it both checks to see if the email is of a valid format in addition to be available to use, not a registered member already.  Messing with the javascript, I have gotten the validator to see my php script, check_email.php using an AJAX post.

However I don't have the right syntax to make the validator make use of the result of the php script to return a message like 'Duplicate" or "Email in use". The html for the email:

```
<!-- EMAIL -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Email address</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6"  style='clear:left;width: 50%;'>
      <input type="text" class="form-control email" name="email" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The relevant part of the javascript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#taskForm').formValidation({
      framework: 'bootstrap',
      icon: {
        // required: 'fa fa-asterisk',
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      fields: {

        'email': {
           validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'The email address is required'
            },
            emailAddress: {
              message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
            }
            ,
            remote: {
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'check_email.php',
              message: 'Duplicate or whatever ...',
              cache: false,
              success: function(result){
                var result=remove_whitespaces(result);
                if(result=='')
               {
                  // Do something ...
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

To see the demo form visit http://dottedi.us/validation/validator.php. To illustrate that the live checker works use the username of 'sowhat' and email address of 'sowhat@dottedi.biz' to test. I have the username working separately with a username checker just to show that it works, not the desired method.  Email is currently broken with my code.

I can modify check_email.php if necessary. Currently it returns $HTML='email exists'; if is a duplicate.

The question: how do I change the structure, syntax of the remote function so that it can make use of a response from check_email.php?

Oh, and here is the php code in check_email.php:

```
<?php
include ("mysql_connection.php");

$HTML = "";
if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']))
{
  $email=strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
  $query="select * from members where LOWER(email)='$email'";
  $res=mysql_query($query);
  $count=mysql_num_rows($res);

  if($count > 0){ $HTML='email exists'; }else{ $HTML=''; }
}

echo $HTML;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept digging and found the answer at: http://formvalidation.io/validators/remote/

1) Changed the relevant javascript to:

```
remote: {
    message: 'This email address is taken',
    url: 'check_email.php',
    type: 'POST'
}
```

2) Changed check_email.php to return JSON format response:

```
if ( $count > 0 ) { $status = false; } else { $status = true; }

if(isset($status))
{
  $data = array(
    "valid"     => $status,
    "email"     => $email // OPTIONAL
  );
 echo json_encode($data);
}
```